# Can not install gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, package-management

I have a problem installing gnome-shell. When I run `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, it says:

```
gnome-shell : Depends: libgnome-keyring0 (>= 3.2.2-2~) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libtelepathy-glib0 (>= 0.15.6) but 0.15.5-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to find `libgnome-keyring0` in synaptic, but it says that I already have the latest version. Please help.

P.S. I don't really need gnome-shell, I just need gnome-tweak-tool, which is gnome-shell dependent.

Answer (score 1):

(This is assuming you are using Unity)

gnome-tweak-tool Isn't gnome-shell dependent as far as I know, you should be able to install it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`. That said, it may be suffering from the same issues as gnome-shell.

Personally, I'd recommend you use ubuntu-tweak. It provides the same options as gnome-tweak-tool, as well as several others such as a janitor, etc. You can install it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```